# Android RecyclerView scrollToPosition not scrolling to bottom of view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that contains messages like whatsapp application, these messages has not a constant height, some of them might be taller than others, so when a message was not taller than my viewport's height, `scrollToPosition(0)` will works fine but if a message was taller than viewport's height, then you may see that `scrollToPosition(0)` will scroll to start of view item (which is a message for my project here), lets say I want to scroll it to end of that message, or scroll to end of all Is there any solution?

PS. my `RecyclerView` is reverse and stacked from bottom

Comment: Please add necessary code and proper screenshot of your problem to get faster response

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Did you try it with handler ?

```
 if (your_arrayList.size() > 0) {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(your_arrayList.size() - 1);
                            }
                        }, 500);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position);
```